# I want to disable the full jsp page when we click on edit in the add page, in single command

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp

i have a **Java Server page** to add a form. When we click on add then the whole page is enable to add fields and save.
And when we click on edit the page is enable as usual, but i want when we click on edit button the whole page should be disable...and i can not define disability in every fields one by one.
i have to do disable  the whole page in single command...i am using eclipse...what should i do ???
Thank you in advance...
This is my code of add form.

```
    <div id="content">
    <section widget-grid id="widget-grid">
    <div class="row">
    <article class="col-sm-12">
    <div jarvis-widget id="standard-datatable-widget" data-widget-color="sttropaz" data-widget-editbutton="false" data-widget-deletebutton="false">
    <header>
    <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-table"></i></span>
    <span><state-breadcrumbs></state-breadcrumbs></span>
    </header>
    <div role="content">
    <div class="widget-body">
    <div class="dataTables_wrapper for-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer ui-corner-all" st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection">
    <form
    .......
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </article>
    </div>
    </section>
    </div>
```

and this is my Java Script code to edit...

```
    $scope.editRow = function(leaveRequest) {
        if (leaveRequest.action == 0) {
            $state.go('app.hrms.hr.leavereq.edit', {
                requestId : leaveRequest.leaveRequestId
            });
        } else if (leaveRequest.action == 1) {
            logger.logError("Cannot Edit This Approved Leave Request");
        } else {
            logger.logError("Cannot Edit This Cancelled Leave Request");
        }
    };
```